# PDFsharp/MigraDoc - why is section.PageSetup.PageWidth = 0?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

In the following C# code I attempt to determine the width of the page so that I can stretch a table with 3 columns to the full width of the page (minus the margins). Initially, I thought that I should set the width of each table column as 1/3 of the page width. However, I found that `section.PageSetup.PageWidth` , `section.PageSetup.LeftMargin` and `section.PageSetup.RightMargin` in the code below return a value of 0.

```
    Section section = document.AddSection();
    section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;
    section.PageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Portrait;

    int sectionWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(section.PageSetup.PageWidth -
                            section.PageSetup.LeftMargin -
                            section.PageSetup.RightMargin);

    int columnWidth = (int)Math.Ceiling(sectionWidth / 3);
```

I assumed that setting the page format to `PageFormat.A4` and the orientation to `Orientation.Portrait` will set the value of `section.PageSetup.PageWidth` accordingly and will also set the values for the margins to some default values. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? I only just started using MigraDoc yesterday. Many thanks.

Comment: This may help you out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966672/pdfsharp-page-size-and-set-margin-issue-c-sharp   (The marked answer says the included code is migradoc).

Comment: Thanks Steve. Yes it helps. I've learnt that I could use this: `PdfSharp.Drawing.XSize size = PdfSharp.PageSizeConverter.ToSize(PdfSharp.PageSize.A4)` to get the width of the whole page which is inclusive of the margins. Now I have to find a way to subtract the default margins to get the "usable width" of the page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.DefaultPageSetup` to query the default margins.

MigraDoc uses self-made nullable values (implemented in the days of .NET 1.1) and values that were not set will return 0, not the default value that will actually be used.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22679890/1015447

Answer (score -1):

This is still happening in **PDFShapr.MigraDoc-wpf (1.50.5147)** I am using with .Net Core 3.1. I solved it by cloning into the section the document's default page setup:

```
var section = this.Document.AddSection();
section.PageSetup = this.Document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
```

And then I used the section's page setup for example to compute the with of the columns of a table relative to the page with:

```
var tbl = section.Headers.Primary.AddTable();
var col1 = tbl.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(PageLineLength(section.PageSetup) * 0.75));    
var col2 = tbl.AddColumn(Unit.FromCentimeter(PageLineLength(section.PageSetup) - col1.Width.Centimeter));
```

Where *PageLineLength*:

```
PageLineLength(PageSetup pageSetup)
{
        return pageSetup.PageWidth.Centimeter - pageSetup.LeftMargin.Centimeter - pageSetup.RightMargin.Centimeter;
}
```